# Jquery .ajaxForm() submit gives 404 error but URL is correct ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

HTML Form

```
<form id="form_CreateAccount" method="post" action="@Url.Action("CreateAccount","Account")" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
         <label>Account Name*</label>
         <input type="text" name="AccountName" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
         <label>Account Type</label>
         @Html.DropDownList("AccountTypeId",new SelectList(ViewBag.AccountTypes,"Id","Type"), new {@class="form-control"})
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success adjust-btn">Create</button>
    </div></form>
```

JQuery .ajaxForm() method:

```
$("#form_CreateAccount").validate();

$("#form_CreateAccount").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function () {
        return $("#form_CreateAccount").valid();
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.success === true) {

        else {

        }
    }
})
```

This is my Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    IAccountService _accountSrvc;

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateAccount(Account account)
    {
        var res = _accountSrvc.CreateAccount(account);
        return Json(new { success = res });
    }
}
```

Without .ajaxForm() method, this form submits successfully but when I submit the form using .ajaxForm() it gives me error 404

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I believe `beforSubmit` should be `beforeSubmit`.

Comment: Yes its "beforeSubmit" not "beforSubmit"

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeSubmit: function () {
    return $("#form_CreateAccount").valid();
}
```

Semicolon after `.valid()` is causing the problem.